# What happens to script triggers when I delete the user that made them?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-workspace, google-account

I want to make a username available for someone else named after the old Tech Admin, however they have a ton of triggers running.
If I delete this user, is there a way to preserve these triggers or transfer them. Or are they affected at all with deletion?

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0):

From [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable):

> **Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them**.

The trigger owner is the user who installed it. There is no way to transfer this ownership.

(Trigger ownership transfer is not possible even if all options are checked when [transferring data on user deletion](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314?hl=en#make_sure&transfer_email&transfer_files&transfer_calendars&forward_email&check_bus&transfer_class&transfer_datastudio&zippy=%2Ctransfer-important-files-and-data%2Cexport-or-transfer-data), and even using [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer)).

Even though I've seen reports ([example](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175741223#comment9)) of triggers running in the background undesirably after the user has been deleted, from my experience, when the user is deleted (either removed from the script or the account is deleted), the trigger stops running, being commonly labeled as `Disabled`.

Therefore, if you want to delete this account, I'd suggest you to install these triggers again with another account.

#### File a feature request:

I'd suggest you to file a feature request in Issue Tracker using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) if you want to add the ability to transfer trigger ownership.